# std::list::merge() fails for lists containing objects

Tags: c++, c++11

I have following situation:

```
#include <list>

struct Example
{
    double p1;
    double p2;
};

void f()
{
    std::list<Example> list1;
    std::list<Example> list2;
    list1.merge(list2);
}
```

During build I get errors:

```
C2672 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found

C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::less<void>::operator() (_Ty1 &&,_Ty2&&) const'
```

If I comment the last line of code, the build is successful. I find it hard to believe that lists that contain objects cannot be merged, so: what am I missing?

PS. I use Visual Studio Community 2015

Comment: `merge` is "merge two sorted lists into a new sorted list", and that requires some means to order the elements for obvious reasons; the "move all the elements from another list to this one" function is `splice`. What do you actually need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/merge) `std::list::merge`:

> Merges two **sorted** lists into one.

And further:

> The first version uses operator< to compare the elements

So you either need to provide `operator<` for your structure or use overloaded version with custom comparator. For example standalone function could be:

```
bool operator<( const Example &e1, const Example &e2 ) {
     return std::tie( e1.p1, e1.p2 ) < std::tie( e2.p1, e2.p2 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible way out of the problem is to define a meaningful relational `operator<` that defines order of your `class Example` objects. This could be done by:

1. An overloaded `operator<` withing the class, which will be implicitly used.
2. Lambda expression directly inserted as a second parameter in the `merge()` function.
3. Separate comparison class, whose object instantiation could be used as second parameter in `merge()`

For example, you could do something like:

```
bool operator< (const Example& lhs, const Example& rhs) const
{
    return lhs.p1 < rhs.p1; // if p1 is used as a criterion   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give std::list::merge a way to compare

```
class Examples{...};
```

for example, you can do this by passing in a lambda

```
void f()
{
    std::list<Example> list1;
    std::list<Example> list2;
    list1.merge(list2,[](Example e1,Example e2)
    {
        return (e1.p1==e2.p1)? (e1.p2 < e2.p2) : (e1.p1 < e2.p1);
    });
}
```

or you can just do

```
using Example = std::pair<double,double>;
```

and then std::list::merge will already know how to compare these (assuming you want the default comparison rules for std::pair)